# Is there a game theoretic concept for this scenario?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

There are two baskets and everyone is able to put money into the baskets. At any given time the content of the baskets is public (everyone can see the amount put so far), but contributions can be done simultaneously. At the end of a certain given fixed time (known in advance to everyone) the basket with more money is declared the winner. The winners (people that put money inside the winning basket), after getting back their contributions to the winning basket, take all the money in the losing basket, in particular the money is divided by the winners proportionally to their contributions to the winning basket. Losers lose all the money.

To further clarify: It's possible for a single player to put money into both basket. But the money from the losing basket it's divided proportionally to the contributions to the winning basket between all the winners.

I envision this scenario to be actually played, therefore the total amount of money is finite and there is a limit to the number of contributions in a given time (realistically the limit will be very loose, like 1 contribution per second, for a game duration of 1 day).

Is there a game theoretic concept for the following scenario? Perhaps this game is known already with a particular name?

References are welcome!

Comment: Please make clear who wins what. There is both a basket "declared winner" and "money (from which basket?) divided proportionally to contributions". What happens to money put in losing baskets?

Comment: @mlc I've edited, it should be clear now.

Comment: Are players allowed to put into both baskets? And so the money in the loosing basket is first given back to the winners (if they contributed to it) and only after this, the remaining money is distributed among the winners? So if everyone puts money into both baskets, nothing is left to be distributed.

Comment: @M.Winter clarified again.

Comment: Here is a situation without a defined result. Let's say the game ends after $T$ seconds. First I put one unit of money into the right basket. Then at any moment $T-1/n,n\in\Bbb N$ I put two units of money into one of the baskets alternatingly, starting with the left one. There is no way to meaningfully compare the amount of money in the baskets at time $T$. Are there some more restrictions? E.g. "only finitely amounts of money can be contributed" (who decides who can spend how much money?) or "contributions can only happen at fixed time steps" (what steps exactly?) etc.

Comment: I realized that only having finite money will not safe you from "undefined results". You need either *finite and discrete money* or *finite and discrete time* (simultaneous contributions are still okay).

Answer (score 0):

If the game is run in one round, this kind of games are called ***Strategic Games***. In addition, if this game is run repeatedly (finitely or infinitely), it would be called ***[Repeated Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_game)***.

Comment: This answer may be too generic. The scenario above is not fully clear, but perhaps a reference to "contest" or "all-pay auction" or "war of attrition" may be closer to the mark.